# bundle product shows price as 0

Tags: magento, installation

I've been reading a lot about this problem but I get nothing that suggests a way out.
I am working with version **1.3.2.4** and after creating a **bundle product**, Magento displays it as price as zero, but gives the "current composition" as the correct value.

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-13_2158.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-13_2158.png)

I already tried to refresh the cache, rebuild the catalog index, and nothing works...
Then I went deep and navigated into the **price.phtml** template under

> template/bundle/catalog/product/view/

and tried to invoke the same method that is showing correctly the value, bu that as well, return zero.

I did notice that Magento has this javascript method

```
bundle.reloadPrice();
```

right after and if invoked I do get the correct price... I can try, using jQuery (or Prototype as Magento uses by default) change the value, but I was trying to this right...

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the product page I'm using this as a work around:

executing this jQuery code:

```
// hide "Price as configured" text
jQuery(".price-as-configured span:first").hide(); 

// hide the 0,00 price
jQuery(".price-box-bundle").hide(); 

// hide the 2nd price (not in image)
jQuery(".product-options-bottom .price-box").hide();
```

will pass **this**:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-13_2338.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-13_2338.png)

into **this**:

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-13_2339.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-13_2339.png)

---

In the product grid list I'm using this code to hide the price/button and add to wish list links

```
// GRID
jQuery("#products-grid-table .price-box").hide();
jQuery("#products-grid-table .button").hide();
jQuery("#products-grid-table .add-to-links").hide();

// LIST 
jQuery("#products-list .price-box").hide();
jQuery("#products-list .button").hide();
jQuery("#products-list .add-to-links").hide();
```

and it will pass **this**

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-14_0005.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-14_0005.png)

into **this**

[alt text http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-14_0006.png](http://www.balexandre.com/temp/2009-10-14_0006.png)

I hope it helps someone ...

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem.
price showed as 0.00.

you have to edit your price-attribute -> show in product-listing: yes

Answer (score 0):

you can use my magento module: https://github.com/head82/KH_ExtendedBundlePrice tested with magento 1.7

Comment: i know, but there are similar problems with newer versions